# How to create private network with preallocated amount of ETH?

Tags: go-ethereum, testing

I am trying to create a private network for testing purposes. What I need is:

1. Fast generating of DAG file.
2. Fast mining of the first block.
3. Address with some preallocated amount of Eth.

I found that this could be done by two ways, the first one is:

- Generate the address.
- Pass it in the genesis file.
- Run `geth --datadir "." init genesis.json`
- Run `geth --dev --mine --datadir "."`

  **PROBLEM:** Address is not preallocated with money (I don't know why, maybe genesis.json file isn't reading properly)

The second one is:

- Generate the address.
- Pass it in the genesis file.
- Run `geth --datadir "." init genesis.json`
- Run `geth --networkid 123 --nodiscover --mine --maxpeers 0 --datadir "."`

  **PROBLEM:** DAG file is generating too slow.

Q: Any suggestions how I can meet all requirements?

**genesis.json:**

```
{
  "nonce": "0xdeadbeefdeadbeef",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x0",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x01",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0xe7b728f368fce77508e4562ef370d3e902bb79dc",
  "alloc": {
    "0xe7b728f368fce77508e4562ef370d3e902bb79dc": {
      "balance": "10000000000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

**geth info:**

```
Geth
Version: 1.4.3-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62 61]
Network Id: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one will work,

Once you’ve generated your account, quit geth with  and remove every folder except keystore/ from your datatir:

```
$ cd <your datadir>
$ rm -rf `ls | grep -v keystore`
```

update your genesis block json, adding the following to the alloc key:

```
"alloc": {
    "<your account address e.g. 0xcc8C048426978c5877212281b8a75F1B4E71a862>": {
        "balance": "10000000000000000000"
    }
}
```

Now re-run the geth command using the newly updated genesis json file and the same datadir, when you check your account balance you will find you now have 10 ether:

Check completes steps in my blog [lightrains.com](https://lightrains.com/blogs/setup-local-ethereum-blockchain-private-testnet)

Comment: Broken link.
Can you please update the url

Comment: @KiranKulkarni Done, please check.

Comment: how to get/set private keys for these accounts?

Comment: @aleebek you create wallet and give the pubkey in the genesis file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with testrpc, it is way faster and has some nice developer features. I struggled with the genesis thing a bit, and just used this:

Install testrpc with: `npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`

Run testrpc like this:

`testrpc -a "10" --seed "2553" --debug --account="<acct number>, <amount of wei in hex>" --account="<another account>,<some amount>"`

Comment: OP is not asking for a rpc method to work, he is trying to solve problem with his current set up. As i understand.

Comment: I uderstood the question as trying to achieve points 1,2 and 3:

1. Fast generating of DAG file.
2. Fast mining of the first block.
3. Address with some preallocated amount of Eth.

I had the same objectives/problem, and I solved it by using testrpc. I was able to setup a test environment for dapps that had preallocated accounts, and is able to run tests faster than a geth rpc.

Comment: @niksmac How can I improve my answer?

Comment: May be, you can propose your answer as an alternative solution or try to answer OPs query. Cheers

Comment: How does my answer not answer OP's question to : "I am trying to create a private network for testing purpose, what I need is:..." 

My answer is a perfect valid way of creating what he is asking for. @niksmac

Comment: Sure you are...